# Why @ViewChild() decorator is not working in this Angular component using PrimeNG FullCalendar?

Tags: angular, primeng, viewchild, angular-decorator, primeng-calendar

I am finding the following problem working on a simple Angular 9 project that uses **PrimeNG FullCalendar** component, this one:
https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fullcalendar

This PrimeNG FullCalendar component is based on this other Angular original component https://fullcalendar.io/docs

**WHAT I HAVE TO DO:** I have to implement an external draggable events as done here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

In the previous example it is used the original Fullcalendar.io component and not the PrimeNG one, but being PrimeNG a wrapping of this component it should be possibile.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:** I created a project containing the calendar and handling simple event as click on a specific date, click on a specific event, moove an event from a date to another date in my calendar.
Here the repository of the code implemented by me untill now: https://bitbucket.org/dgs_poste_team/soc_calendar/src/master/

**WHAT IS MY PROBLEM:** As you can see into my **fullcalendar.component.hml** file I have this code:

```
<p>fullcalendar works!</p>

<div class="content-section implementation">
  <p-fullCalendar #fullcalendar
                  [events]="events"
                  [options]="options">
  </p-fullCalendar>
</div>

<div #external>
  <p>
    <strong>Draggable Events</strong>
  </p>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 1</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 2</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 3</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 4</div>
  <div class='fc-event'>My Event 5</div>
</div>
```

So the **p-fullCalendar** is the PrimeNG component rendering my calendard and it is referenced by **#fullcalendar**.

Then I have a div referenced by **#external** containing the external events that I need to drag into my calendar.

This external events drag operation is not working.

The problems seems to depend by the fact that the typescript component code can't access to this div **#external** reference.

Into my **fullcalendar.component.ts** file I have defined this class implementing the logic behind my component (I am implementing it following the provided example):

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../event.service';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import { FullCalendar } from 'primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fullcalendar',
  templateUrl: './fullcalendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fullcalendar.component.css']
})
export class FullcalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  events: any[];
  options: any;
  header: any;

  @ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar: FullCalendar;
  @ViewChild('external') external: ElementRef;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.eventService.getEvents().then(events => { this.events = events;});
    //this.eventService.getEvents().then(res => {console.log(res)} )
    console.log("bla");
    //console.log(this.events.length);

    this.options = {
        plugins:[ dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin ],
        defaultDate: '2017-02-01',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        editable: true,

        dateClick: (dateClickEvent) =>  {         // <-- add the callback here as one of the properties of `options`
          console.log("DATE CLICKED !!!");
        },

        eventClick: (eventClickEvent) => {
          console.log("EVENT CLICKED !!!");
        },

        eventDragStop: (eventDragStopEvent) => {
          console.log("EVENT DRAG STOP !!!");
        }
    };


    console.log("external: " + this.external);
    console.log(this.fullcalendar.getCalendar().getEvents);

    new Draggable(this.external.nativeElement, {
      itemSelector: '.fc-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText
        };
      }
    });

  }

}
```

As you can see I have these two properties decorated by **@ViewChild**

```
@ViewChild('fullcalendar') fullcalendar: FullCalendar;
@ViewChild('external') external: ElementRef;
```

I think that for some reason that I can't understand these two lines are not correctly working because in my console I obtain the following error on this line:

```
new Draggable(this.external.nativeElement, {
    ................................................
    ................................................
    ................................................
});
```

This is the error when it try to access to **this.external.nativeElement** property:

```
core.js:6272 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCalendar' of undefined
    at FullcalendarComponent.ngOnInit (fullcalendar.component.ts:56)
    at callHook (core.js:4770)
    at callHooks (core.js:4734)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4674)
    at refreshView (core.js:11998)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13461)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11701)
    at refreshView (core.js:12036)
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (core.js:12114)
    at tickRootContext (core.js:13668)
```

As you can see in my code I also added this line to debug pourpose (into the **ngOnInit()** method):

```
console.log("external: " + this.external);
```

and the console output is:

```
external: undefined
```

so it seems to me that it can't access to the **#external** div reference.

Is my assumption correct? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I try to fix this bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because `ngOnInit` is too early for `ViewChild`, there's a special hook for it `AfterViewInit`, all `ViewChild` have been initialised when it's triggered and you can access `this.external.nativeElement` for example.

Here you can find an example how they use it: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#responding-to-view-changes

```js
export class AfterViewComponent implements  AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('external') external: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    consoloe.log(this.external.nativeElement); // works
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I try your solution...only a doubt, why in this correctly working example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) the author put the  access to "this.external.nativeElement" into ngOnInit() and it works correctly?

Comment: Good question, I guess a characteristic of angular 7 and a bit of luck, nevertheless according to the docs the right place to access ViewChild is ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: I tried your solution. It works only in part, infact ngAfterViewCheked() hook is performed multiple time and it create some other problem in the behavior, but using this other hook ngAfterViewInit() that is performed only once after ngAfterViewCheked() it works fine. If you update your response with this hook I will be happy to accept your solution !!! Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get it, in my answer I point exactly to ngAfterViewInit, should I get rid of `ngAfterViewCheked` from it?

Answer (score 1):

try this.calendarComponent.getApi()

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular

Comment: The official FC doesn't support later Angular, like 10/11. u will get ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApi' of undefined